# how can i add " to a variable in php?

Tags: php

so I'm trying to make a variable that contains a " sign 
like if i had a variable called `$x`
i want my variable

```
$y = """ , $x , """
```

but i can't just write """ so what is the method of adding a " to a variable

im using php 5 but i don't think that's gonna help i mean im justwriting more because this site doesn't allow me to post but i can't explain more and i cant find my answer in another place
and again more writing yada yada , some questions are small so WHY just WHY does it think it's incomplete

Comment: You need to escape the quote, or use single quotes - `$y = "\"" . $x. "\"";` or `$y = '"'. $x.'"';`

Comment: U need to escape `"` with `\"`... Try `"\""` or better use single quotes `'"'`. When using single quotes and you need a `'` you also have to escape it with `'\''`

Comment: huh i swear i just tried doing `'"'` from a moment and didnt work maybe a messed up some where but uhh now it work , wow im embarrassed

Comment: wait no it works when i echo it but not when i try to create a var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
$x =11;
$y = '"""'.$x.'"""'; 

echo $y;
```

Result
"""11"""

Answer (score 0):

now i finally figured out what i was doing wrong , i was using , instead of . between the values so the final code is

```
$y = '"' . $x . '"' ;
```